# How to access subjects of selected mails in Apple Mail using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, macos, automation, applescript

Starting with 10.10, Apple started to also support JavaScript for Automation instead of AppleScript but I really have a hard time to understand their JavaScript syntax.

E.g. let's take this easy AppleScript:

```
tell application "Mail"
    set seletedMails to selection
    repeat with aMail in seletedMails
        set aSubject to subject of aMail
        display dialog aSubject
    end repeat
end tell
```

All it does is displaying a dialog with the subject of every selected e-mail in the Mail application. Can't get much simpler than that, can it? Should be easy to do that in JavaScript, right? So here's my code

```js
function main ( ) {
    var Mail = Application('com.apple.mail')
    Mail.includeStandardAdditions = true
    var selectedMails = Mail.selection  
    for (var aMail of selectedMails) {
        Mail.displayDialog(aMail.subject)
    }
}
main()
```

Result:

```
Error -1700: Can't convert types.
```

Okay... what did I do wrong? I cannot call `selectedMails.length` either, same error. `selectedMails` doesn't seem to be an array at all. Oh, wait, when I do this `var selectedMails = Mail.selections` (note the plural form!), then I can do `selectedMails.length`, but it always gives me 0, regardless how many mails I have selected. And when I do this (note, also uses the plural form):

```js
function main ( ) {
    var Mail = Application('com.apple.mail')
    Mail.includeStandardAdditions = true
    var selectedMails = Mail.selections
    for (var aMail of selectedMails) {
        Mail.displayDialog(aMail.subject)
    }
}
main()
```

It only says:

```
Error -2700: Script error.
```

What extremely helpful error messages we get here, not!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close.  
Generally, with JXA, you need to use a parenthesis at the end of a command to GET the values.  So, you needed:

`Mail.selection()`
`aMail.subject()`

Here's the complete script, with my changes:

```js
'use strict';

var app = Application.currentApplication()
app.includeStandardAdditions = true

var Mail = Application('com.apple.mail')
    var selectedMails = Mail.selection();
    
    for (var aMail of selectedMails) {
        app.displayDialog(aMail.subject());
    }
```

I also added the `var app = Application.currentApplication()`, as this is considered the best practice by many, and used by Apple in all of their documents.

See [Introduction to JavaScript for Automation Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/InterapplicationCommunication/RN-JavaScriptForAutomation/Articles/Introduction.html)

Comment: So basically properties in JavaScript bridging are in fact no properties but functions? Apple could at least have pointed that out when viewing the scripting dictionary and then choosing JavaScript as a language  I'll give it a try and accept your answer if this works.

Comment: @Mecki, have you read the JXA Release Notes from Apple (link above)?  They do state that you need the parenthesis to get the values.

Comment: Yeah, now I've seen it. But when you want to find out what kind of automation is possible, you typically open `Script Editor` (the app) and then you go `File > Open Dictionary...` and choose the app you want to script. In this window you can switch between `AppleScript` and `JavaScript`; it would have been easy to just display properties with parenthesis there. Not doing so is a massive failure IMHO.